# MVC application deploy to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

I am trying to deploy my MVC application to server with IIS installed on it. I added an application on IIS, published the application via Visual Studio to correct directory, but apparently when I try to run it through my IIS Manager, it gives me an error that the requested URL is way too long and looks strange. It is of form:

> http://localhost:80/ClassDeclarations/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FClassDeclarations%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FClassDeclarations%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FClassDeclarations%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FClassDeclarations%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FClassDeclarations%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FClassDeclarations%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FClassDeclarations%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FClassDeclarations%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FClassDeclarations%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FClassDeclarations%252525252525252525252525252525252FMyAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252F
>   And obviously it is not what I would expect. What can I do wrong that this happens? Btw, yes, the project uses Entity Framework.

Comment: seem like you have infinite redirect to login page. check your login page to see whether there's any logic that can cause it redirects to itself, even if user's unauthenticated

Comment: @PhuongNguyen Why would it even move to login page, since the main page is just the application name. And when I run the app through Visual Studio, everything works fine. Isn't that maybe a problem of connection strings with database and sharing instance of it? (I heard of it but I don't know how to manage it)

Comment: Why would the *database* have something to do with a URL? Lots of people suggest the most bizzare reasons for what in the end are simple bugs caused by typos. In any case, it's pretty obvious that there is an infinite redirect - the same URL is repeated. You can monitor this if eg you use Fiddler to monitor the requests and redirects. Or if you debug your application, by specifying the IIS server instead of IIS Express on the Debug page

Comment: Apparently, after waiting 15 minutes, it started working! Yay, thank you for your support. But then another problem appeared. The problem is that it crashed (throws error) whenever I try to do anything with database. What may be the problem? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: That you don't have a database? Wrong database name? Wrong server? What *is* the error? Why don't you just install IIS on a *different* machine and try deploying to it before going to production? What you describe is almost certainly caused because you use local addresses etc